# How to join multiple files (any number) on varying fields, filling up missing fields with a default value

Tags: bash, join, awk, posix

I posted this question because it is a more general use-case than the existing ones about joining multiple files, and I stumbled on a little problem while writing a solution for it.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do (the number of input files can vary):

```
$ cat f1.tsv
F11 F12 F13
111 A   113
211 B   213

$ cat f2.tsv
F21 F22
121 D

$ cat f3.tsv
F31 F32 F33 F24
131 132 133 C
231 232 233 A
331 332 333 D

$ cat fn.tsv
Fn1 Fn2 Fn3
B   102 103
F   202 203
D   302 303
C   402 403
```

To join the above files, the user will provide `f1.tsv f2.tsv f3.tsv fn.tsv` (the files) as arguments and `2 2 4 1` (the fields to join) as parameters; the expected output would be:

```
F11 F13 F21 F31 F32 F33 Fn2 Fn3 KEY
111 113 0   231 232 233 0   0   A
211 213 0   0   0   0   102 103 B
0   0   0   131 132 133 402 403 C
0   0   121 331 332 333 302 303 D
0   0   0   0   0   0   202 203 F
```

**note:** the fields in the input and output are delimited with a single Tab character

Here's what I've written so far:

```bash
awk -v join='2 2 4 1' -v empty='0' '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "\t"

        if ( err = (ARGC <= 2 || split(join,joinArr,"[[:space:],]") != ARGC-1) )
            exit
    }
    FNR == 1 {
        ++fileNumber

        j = joinArr[fileNumber]+0
        if ( err = (j < 1 || NF < j) )
            exit

        rec = sep = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            if (i != j) {
                rec = rec sep $i
                sep = OFS
            }
        header = (fileNumber == 1 ? rec : header OFS rec)
        next
    }
    {
        rec = sep = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            if (i != j) {
                rec = rec sep $i
                sep = OFS
            }
        keys[$j]
        records[fileNumber,$j] = rec
    }
    END {
        if (err)
            exit err

        print header, "KEY"

        for (k in keys) {
            rec = sep = ""
            for (i = 1; i <= fileNumber; i++) {
                rec = rec sep ((i,k) in records ? records[i,k] : empty)
                sep = OFS
            }
            rec = rec sep k
            print rec
        }
    }
' f1.tsv f2.tsv f3.tsv fn.tsv
```

But I get this:

```
F11 F13 F21 F31 F32 F33 Fn2 Fn3 KEY
111 113 0   231 232 233 0   A
211 213 0   0   102 103 B
0   0   131 132 133 402 403 C
0   121 331 332 333 302 303 D
0   0   0   202 203 F
```

**remark:** I need it to work on Linux and macOS, so I'm using POSIX `awk`, but `perl` and possibly `python` (compatible with 2.7 **and** 3.x) could also be an option.

Comment: Can a key value, e.g. `A` appear multiple times in the join column of a file?

Comment: @EdMorton not in the data that the script is targetting. That would be a little tricky to handle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General issue is that `empty` is defined as a single field; it should be defined as a variable number of fields based on the number of fields in each file.

Tweaking current code to generate an `empty[fileNumber]` array:

```
awk -v join='2 2 4 1' -v empty_str='0' '                                     # modified
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "\t"

        if ( err = (ARGC <= 2 || split(join,joinArr,"[[:space:],]") != ARGC-1) )
            exit
    }
    FNR == 1 {
        ++fileNumber

        j = joinArr[fileNumber]+0
        if ( err = (j < 1 || NF < j) )
            exit
   
        rec = sep = empty_rec = ""                                           # modified
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            if (i != j) {
                rec = rec sep $i
                empty_rec = empty_rec sep empty_str                          # new
                sep = OFS
            }
        header = (fileNumber == 1 ? rec : header OFS rec)
        empty[fileNumber] = empty_rec                                        # new
        next
    }
    {
        rec = sep = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            if (i != j) {
                rec = rec sep $i
                sep = OFS
            }
        keys[$j]
        records[fileNumber,$j] = rec
    }
    END {
        if (err)
            exit err

        print header, "KEY"

        for (k in keys) {
            rec = sep = ""
            for (i = 1; i <= fileNumber; i++) {
                rec = rec sep ((i,k) in records ? records[i,k] : empty[i])   # modified
                sep = OFS
            }
            rec = rec sep k
            print rec
        }
    }
' f1.tsv f2.tsv f3.tsv fn.tsv
```

**NOTES:**

- while not explicitly stated in the description, the current (and tweaked) code assumes we only have to deal with missing rows
- put another way: within a given file, all rows will contain the same number of columns (ie, we don't have to worry about some lines missing one or more columns)

This generates:

```
F11     F13     F21     F31     F32     F33     Fn2     Fn3     KEY
111     113     0       231     232     233     0       0       A
211     213     0       0       0       0       102     103     B
0       0       0       131     132     133     402     403     C
0       0       121     331     332     333     302     303     D
0       0       0       0       0       0       202     203     F
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at your code except a glance to see how you were calling and beginning it so idk what's wrong with it, sorry, but FWIW I'd do it like this, using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v joinStr='2 2 4 1' -v empty='0' '
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
    split(joinStr,joinArr,/[[:space:],]+/)
}
FNR == 1 {
    prevNumOutCols = numOutCols
    joinColNr = joinArr[++numFiles]
    for ( inColNr=1; inColNr<=NF; inColNr++ ) {
        if ( inColNr != joinColNr ) {
            hdr = hdr $inColNr OFS
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    numOutCols = prevNumOutCols
    key = $joinColNr
    for ( inColNr=1; inColNr<=NF; inColNr++ ) {
        if ( inColNr != joinColNr ) {
            vals[key,++numOutCols] = $inColNr
        }
    }
}
!seen[key]++ {
    keys[++numKeys] = key
}
END {
    print hdr "KEY"
    for ( keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++ ) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        for ( outColNr=1; outColNr<=numOutCols; outColNr++ ) {
            val = ( (key,outColNr) in vals ? vals[key,outColNr] : empty )
            printf "%s%s", val, OFS
        }
        print key
    }
}
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh f1.tsv f2.tsv f3.tsv fn.tsv
F11     F13     F21     F31     F32     F33     Fn2     Fn3     KEY
111     113     0       231     232     233     0       0       A
211     213     0       0       0       0       102     103     B
0       0       121     331     332     333     302     303     D
0       0       0       131     132     133     402     403     C
0       0       0       0       0       0       202     203     F
```

The output rows will be in the order that the key values appear across all files.

I didn't use `join` as a variable name since that's the name of [a function in the gawk manual for merging arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Join-Function) so I didn't want this code to potentially clash with anyone using that function or confuse anyone expecting `join` to mean that function name.

Comment: Thank you Ed; nice trick with `numOutCols`

Comment: @Fravadona you're welcome. Yeah, I tend to think of and write most transformation code like this where we select specific columns in terms of inColNrs and outColNrs, it's the only way I can keep the different fields straight in my head!